# Domain Driven Design: reference between entities of different aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, dddd

I'm trying to develop my first application using Domain Driven Design rules and patterns.

In my business scenario I have to manage the list of Customers and to track all the package that are sent to a specific customer destination.
So, following the rules, it turns out that:

- Customer is an Entity which is also an AggregateRoot.
- Destination is an Entity which is child of Customer (because it doesn’t make sense without a Customer)
- Package is an Entity. It is also another AggregateRoot because is a different transactional boundary
  I developed the Customer Aggregate with the method AddDestination(string destinationName …) that is responsable of creating a new Destination for the Customer.

Now I need to develop the Package class, where I have to maintain a reference to the destination where the package has been shipped. Following the DDD rules I can't reference the child entity id directly because I can’t reference entity that are child of another aggregate.

What do I have to do?

1. Do I have to create a new ValueObejct with the required data of the Destination and expose it? (in this way I'm able to preserve the encapsulation and the rules of the Destionation which is accessible in writing only through Customer AggregateRoot). In this way external classes can access the fields of the Destination and perform logics/check using those but can't alternate the state of the destination.
2. Do I have to add a DestinationNumber field (progressive within customer), create a ValueObject that contains CustomerId and DestinationNumber and use it in the Package aggregate?
3. ?

Can someone please help me? Please elaborate the reply because I'd like to understand more this cases.

Comment: You wrote that destination doesn't make sense without a customer and later it sounded like you want to point to the destination only. Which one is true?
Depending on the answer I'd suggest to either just copy all the destination data as a value object into Package (option 1 if customer doesn't matter much here) or store CustomerId + DestinationNumber combination from (option 2 if destination makes no sense without customer).

Comment: Thx @urmaul for the reply.Destination in my ubiquitous language doesn't make sense without a Customer because every Destination is related to one Customer (while Customer can have multiple destinations).Destionation has its own id so can i reference to it or i can't because Destination doesn't make sense without a Customer?

Comment: My DB schema is something like this: TAB_Customers(ID, name), TAB_Destionations(ID, CustomerId, name), TAB_Packages(ID, DestinationId, Date). It is ok if i introduce the DestinationNumber in my ubiquitous languige only beacuse i need it in my value objects? 
I'm doing a mistake considering Destinations as child entityes of Customer? Because i can reference only to it from my package i need to consider it as another AggregateRoot?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I would assume that this **Package** *must* be delivered somewhere, to a **Destination**.

I would also assume that **Customer** is indeed an Entity and also an Aggregate Root because it would have behaviours such as changing names, etc. **Package** is also an Entity, and also an Aggregate Root of itself, since it has different transaction boundary from **Customer** and also has some behavior (like *addDestination*).

Here, I don't see that **Destination** should be an Entity, because it does not have any behavior or identity of itself, rather it just contains a fact that this **Destination** refers to a **Customer**. So, I would model **Destination** as a Value Object instead, with an attribute of CustomerId (this can be done because **Customer** is an Aggregate Root).

**Package**'s *addDestination*'s argument would be a Value Object of **Destination**. If **Package** should ever have to change the destination, it can just create another instance of **Destination** and discard the old one.

Also, it does not make sense if **Destination** is a child of **Customer**, since there might be some **Customers** that are not delivered anything yet. Instead, I would model **Destination** as a child of **Package**, since it makes sense that every creation of **Package**, it should have a **Destination** (under the assumption that any **Package** must be delivered). And so **Package** and **Destination** are in the same aggregate.

Comment: In my domain every **Customer** must have at least one **Destination** in order to be "visible" in the Package department subsystem so it is correct to have **Destinations** child of **Customers**. Now, It is ok using a discriminant such a CusotmerId in my **Destination** ValueObject only becasuse i need a key to distinguish the same destination name for two different **Customers** or is better to treat **Destinations** as Entities? Because with this "trick" i can treat all the entities as value objects by inserting the properties that compose the key into the ValueObject.Is that correct?

Comment: Is Package in another subsystem? If so, is the meaning of "Destination" in the Customer subsystem slightly different than the meaning of "Destination" in the Package subsystem?

If those are in a separate bounded context, you could create **Destination** as a Value Object as a child of **Customer** in Customer subsystem, then just create another **Destination** as an Aggregate Root inside Package subsystem, since both "Destination" means something slightly different

Answer (score 0):

Aggregates in DDD are more about *transaction boundaries* rather than denoting if one entity's existence makes sense without the other.

---

**Assumption A** - *Destination* should rather be an **aggregate**

If it makes sense in your domain to modify ***Destination*** within it's own transaction without having to take a *Customer* in account then it might be you missed Destination as an aggregate on it's own.

This would also make sense if Destinations would be shared between customers or would be moved from one Customer to another (by identity reference of course).

---

**Assumption B** - *Destination* is definitely a **child entity** of *Customer*

If on the other hand only the customer aggregate can make sure that business invariants for customer's destinations can be met at all times, *Destination* should only be changed within the transaction boundaries of the *customer* and thus stay a child entity of customer.

In your ***Package*** aggregate you could of course only remember the Destinations id if you only need it for reading purpose, for instance.

But think this is not a good idea. On the hand not in including the Customer's id as well in the reference makes this relationship less explicit. And on the other hand if Destination is really an entity (and not a value object only) the id of Destination only needs to be unique in the domain within the boundaries of the corresponding customer.

So in case Destination is really a child entity of Customer I would go with your ***option 2*** by introducing a reference value object such as, e.g. *CustomerDestination* including the customer id and whatever identifier is suitable to identify the destination within the scope of the specific customer.

Note: this does not have an influence on your database model where you might, depending on how you design it, still need some globally unique surrogate Id in the database.

Comment: Ok thx. Basically what you are suggesting in **Assumption B** is that if i can find a composite key for **Destination** that would be an Entity, otherwise it's only a Value Object? According to DDD it's ok to create a Value Object only to protect the invariant of a child Entity? For example can i craete a Value Object with all the Entity properties only to expose it outside protecting the entity invariance? Example: Order with rows exposed outside as OrderRowValueObject with OrderId, OrderLineId, Price properties (of course i'm supposing that OrderRow is a child entity of Order)?

Comment: Yes, it would also be OK to expose only the properties you need rather than id references for fetching on demand. It really depends on your situation. If you do not store reference ids in a value object but a value object with all properties instead you also have to take care of data synchronisation - i.e. if the Destination is updated for the Customer the Package also needs to be updated (either directly or with some background job). If you more often only need the reference ids in use cases involving the Package I would go with that...

Comment: ...but if you really have lots of **writes** to Packages where you also need Destination data it might be better for you to always keep the required Destination properties available in the Package already. But please also don't forget, that for only **reading** data you should not query via your domain model classes (aggregates) but rather directly read from the data store the most suitable and performant way you can. Because for reading you do not need to adhere to any business rules as you are not changing anything and thus you **cannot** bring your model into an inconsistent state.

Comment: Yes i'm applying CQRS so i'm refering the questions to the write side. I think i did't explain well what i was meaning. Immagine that you have an Entity (E1, that is also an AggregateRoot) with a child entity (CE1). Now, for some reasons, i need to reference CE1 from another Aggregate (E2). Can i expose a ValueObject with all the property of CE1 to access (and reference the id) the data from E2 or it's not correct? I'm thinking about cases where the same fisical entity has invariants splitted between two aggregates. Should i split the same entity although i have only one pshiscal entity?